# How to get list of network requests done from javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I am loading new web page in new tab from my javascript by writing below code. `window.open('www.gmail.com','_blank')`
While the new tab is loading I would like to read all redirected url's in the network tab(chrome devtools). I tried to reload all url's using `performance.getEntriesByType("resource");` but here the issue is my existing application is refreshing.
To make this question more clear.
1) I have my existing application lets a gmail only.
2) When I click on one button(lets say compose in gmail ), it has to open new web page in different tab.
3) When the new page gets loaded completely I would like to read all loaded urls' in the network tab in chrome dev tools.
4) While  reading those url's from chrome network tab my existing page  should not refresh.

Comment: Devtools has an option in its settings to auto-open for popups https://puu.sh/Furct/344ce2a68b.png

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What I am trying here is to read all network url's from chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you want is possible. See [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

You could manually export the network data as JSON (saves as .har). Then `JSON.parse()` using the console or external script. See [Export data from Chrome developer tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521942/export-data-from-chrome-developer-tool).

Edit:
Maybe you can modify the XMLHttpRequest object to add an <s>onOpen</s> onSend listener. See [How can I modify the XMLHttpRequest responsetext received by another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447335/how-can-i-modify-the-xmlhttprequest-responsetext-received-by-another-function/26447781#26447781)